# Image not loading React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working at this e-commerce website and I'm having some trouble. Everything is working fine, but the images just wont load.

[Data code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0CtFY.jpg)
This is the information that is shown along the image.

[Import Data code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHkeo.jpg)
These are the imports

[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rIqT.jpg)
Img src code thats not working

[Image not loading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cr6pJ.jpg)
Thats the output

As you may see I've put the path to the image file and I can't figure out what is causing the image to not load.

This code is the product information:

```
export const Data = [
{
    _id:1,
    img:'images/lightsaber.png',
    title:'Light Saber',
    price:'570',
    category:'weapon',
    details:'Lightsabers consisted of a plasma blade, powered by a kyber crystal, that was emitted from a usually metal hilt and could be shut off at will.',
    count:1,
    isInCart: false
}
```

This one is the where the product should be shown:

```
    import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Data } from './Data';

const Product = (props) => {

    const {data} = props;

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div className="product">
                <div className="box-img">
                    <Link to={'/details/${data._id}'}> <img src={data.img} alt={data.name}></img> </Link>
                </div>

                <div className="product-details">
                    <h3>{data.title}</h3>
                    <h4>${data.price}</h4>
                </div>

                <div className="product-btn">
                    <button>Add to cart</button>
                </div>

                <div className="inCart">
                    <span>Already in cart</span>
                </div>
                
            </div>

        </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default Product;
```

The images are in a paste called "images"

Comment: How do you use `<Product />` component? Are you sure you are passing `data` there? Also it's important to note your file is containing an array, probably you need to use `.map()` to iterate through to represent each elements from there as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the full address of each image. Suppose you are running your code on a local server (for example http://localhost:3001 ) and your images are in the project folder in the 'images' subfolder, the right address for each image would be the combination of these two:
http://localhost:3001/images/image_name

You can do the following:

```
const BaseUrl = *your server's address*
<img src={data.img} alt={BaseUrl + data.name}></img>
```

Comment: there's a typo, the correct way is:   src={BaseUrl + data.img}